# Custom Checkboxes Failing on Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, checkbox

I'm trying to make custom checkboxes with CSS3, which is working great on Chrome.  On Firefox... not so much.

> #### Edit: it seems to be working fine on Firefox 37.
>
> The answer below is still relevant, but the style related issues from mid 2013 are resolved.
>
> IE support isn't mentioned here but edits/answers regarding it are welcome.

### [demo](http://codepen.io/brigand/pen/narzd)

The HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="first"/>
<label for="first">This is pretty awesome</label>
```

The CSS:

```
input[type=checkbox] {
  appearance: none;
  background: transparent;
  position: relative;
}
input[type=checkbox]::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: '';
  text-align: center;
  background: #aaa;
  display: block;
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 1;
  color: black;
  border: 3px solid black;
}
input[type=checkbox] + label {
  line-height: 48px;
  margin: 0 15px 0 15px;
}
input[type=checkbox]:hover::after {
  content: '';
  background: #32cd32;
  opacity: .3;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked::after {
  content: '\2713';
  background: #32cd32;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked:hover::after {
  opacity: 1;
}
input[type=checkbox],
input[type=checkbox]::after {
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  font-size: 46px;
  line-height: 48px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

<sub>Note: I removed vendor prefixes, and things like user-select for brevity.  The full code is in the pen.</sub>

What do I need to change to have it look the same on Firefox as it does on Chrome?

Desired:

[image: chrome desired look]

Not desired:

[image: firefox bad look]

Comment: it's impossible with pure CSS. url:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587669/css-after-pseudo-element-on-input-field

Comment: other mozilla link: http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=291007

Comment: Sorry, I fixed the picture.  So the after text *is* showing up on Firefox, but it's not showing the border-radius or box-shadow.  I'd even be willing to hide the checkbox somehow.  I'm trying to hide the checkbox, and make the `::after` a `::before` of the label.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I managed to fix it as much as seems possible (I'd still love a better solution, if one exists).  I switched all of the selectors from

```
input[type=checkbox]::after
```

to

```
input[type=checkbox] + label::after
```

Downside:

- requires a label

But:

- HTML requires input elements to have a label

Conclusion:

- only bad for invalid HTML

Comment: I'm having this exact same issue. Did you ever find another way not requiring a label?

Comment: Nope, the only other solutions require JavaScript to mimic the functionality of a label.

Answer (score 16):

You can enable custom styles for checkbox specifically for mozilla browser by adding this property and it worked for me.

`-moz-appearance:initial`

Comment: You, Sir, is a hero. Worked as expected.

Answer (score 2):

doesnt technically need a LABEL, but does need control over the mark up to ensure there is a target-able sibling immediately after the checkbox.

i.e.

```css
input[type=checkbox] + span::after{
  display:block;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background:yellow;
  display:block;

}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + span::after{
  display:block;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background:yellow;
  display:block;

}
```

```html
    <input type="checkbox"></input>
    <span class="targetMe"></span>
```

target the span using the sibling selector and :after elements as above.

Might as well put in a label tho at this point... :P

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `:after` and `::after` technically create an element as the last *child* of the element the pseudoselector is applied to.  Firefox doesn't like to create children inside of its checkboxes.  This is actually part of a bigger topic which is [replaced elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Replaced_element).

You will see the same issue with the `:before` and `::before` pseudoelements not working on checkboxes because they would create elements as a first *child* element within the element being selected.